Lack of registered modules in Jackson objectmapper after Spring boot upgrade
Trying to upgrade my app, dependencies to be changed:
spring-cloud from 2023.0.0 -> 2023.0.3
Spring boot from 3.2.5 -> 3.3.2
Noticed issues with de/serialization, it looks like inheritance was not set.
Error:
Cannot construct instance of `my interface` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information

That interface is related with payload of message that we send using spring cloud messaging.
In my project, we are declaring sub/types with definition of Module as spring bean:
SimpleAbstractTypeResolver resolver = new SimpleAbstractTypeResolver() {
        //this is a workaround for https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/2019
       
        @Override
        public JavaType resolveAbstractType(DeserializationConfig config, BeanDescription typeDesc) {
            return findTypeMapping(config, typeDesc.getType());
        }
    };
    resolver.addMapping(X,Y);
    module.setAbstractTypes(resolver);

When I'm debugging the current configuration (class org.springframework.cloud.function.json.JacksonMapper) I can see 10 registered modules (including custom ones), but on branch with an upgrade only one (it is jackson-datatype-jsr310)
Any suggestions?
Tried to remove that workaround in module definition
but it did not helped.
===============
(Part Added)
Spring class ContextFunctionCatalogAutoConfiguration from project spring-cloud-function-context
On version 4.1.0 code fetch existing ObjectMapper
private JsonMapper jackson(ApplicationContext context) {
ObjectMapper mapper;
try {
 mapper = (ObjectMapper)context.getBean(ObjectMapper.class);
} catch (Exception var4) {
mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);

}
return new JacksonMapper(mapper);
}
On version 4.1.3 code creates a new mapper:
private JsonMapper jackson(ApplicationContext context) {
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_TRAILING_TOKENS, true);
return new JacksonMapper(mapper);

}

Please provide a codebase example for testing via github.

Looks like it is just https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/issues/1159
